# How to call variable from within a function

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to be able to call a variable set earlier by a script in order to control an element.

Script to load map onto page

```
<script>
window.scribblemaps = {
    settings: {
        baseAPI: "google",
        key: 'key'
    }
};

var loadmap = function () {
    var sm = new 
        scribblemaps.ScribbleMap(document.getElementById('ScribbleMap'),
            { controlMode: { 'mapType': scribblemaps.ControlModes.SMALL } }
    );
}
</script>
```

html which creates a div to display map

```
<div class="SM" id="ScribbleMap"></div>
```

javascript to save the map

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#start_design').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('href');
            var offset = $(id).offset().top - 70;
            $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: offset}, 1000);
        })

        $('#save_design_maps').on('click',function(){
            var project_name = $('#project_name');
            if( project_name.val() !== '') {
                project_name.css('border-color', '');
                var sm = document.getElementById('ScribbleMap');
                var uid = (new Date().getTime()).toString(36);
                var title = project_name.val();
                var details = {
                    "id": uid,
                    "password": "aaa",
                    "title": title,
                    "description": title,
                    "secure": false,
                    "listed": false,
                    "projectId": "ID",
                    "groupCode": "<groupCode>"
                };
                // console.log(sm);
                // console.log(JSON.stringify(sm.data.getSmJSON(), null, 2));

                sm.map.save(details, function (completeEvent) { }, function (errorEvent) { });
                sm.map.addListener(scribblemaps.MapEvent.MAP_SAVED, function (event) {
                    alert('Map is saved!');
                    var sm_share_link = 'https://www.scribblemaps.com/maps/view/' + title.replace(/\s+/g, '_') + '/' + uid;
                    $('#map_url').val(sm_share_link);
                    console.log(sm_share_link);
                });

                sm.map.addListener(scribblemaps.MapEvent.MAP_SAVE_ERROR, function (event) {
                    alert('Map can not be saved!');
                });
            } else {
                alert('Please fill the Project Name Field');
                project_name.css('border-color', 'red');
            }

        });

    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {

    });

    $(window).resize(function() {

    });

    $(window).load(function() {

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Expected result is for the javascript to call a function on the Scribblemap api to Save the map.

Actual result is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: So that means `var sm = document.getElementById('ScribbleMap');` is not returning anything `console.log(sm);`

Comment: Your `sm` is a `DOM Node`. You cannot call `map` on it.

Comment: @AmitDas He's not calling the `map` function, he's calling `sm.map.save()` and `sm.map.addListener()`.

Comment: Where do you call `loadmap()`? It needs to do `return sm;`, and then you can save that result in a variable to use in other functions. Or it can assign the map to a global variable.

Comment: Is that your real key? If so maybe you shouldn't post it.

Comment: Aahh... My bad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since html elements don't have the `map` attribute I believe that you are trying to access this `sm`:

```js
var loadmap = function () {
    var sm = new 
        scribblemaps.ScribbleMap(document.getElementById('ScribbleMap'),
            { controlMode: { 'mapType': scribblemaps.ControlModes.SMALL } }
    );
}
```

You have to pass this `sm` instance to your function in order for it to work.

Comment: Thanks Paul, this is now fixed by declaring the sm variable outside of the function.  Thanks for your help!